# Program can't change file name because its being used in another process?

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms, updates

I have a problem with an updater application when modifying the main applications exe file.

Whenever the updater is called by itself it works fine, but if called by the main application it complains that its still open.

Heres the Code from the Main application when it closes and calls the updater if there is an update.

```
Private Sub btn_Force_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Force.Click
    If MsgBox("Reverting to an old update risks the corruption of current data, this is not recommended unless instructed. Do you wish to proceed?", vbExclamation + vbYesNoCancel, "Warning") = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Shell("C:\Users\...\AppData\Roaming\...\Updater.exe")
        Application.Exit()
    End If
End Sub
```

The updater replaces the whole folder, because of installation files.

So the order is...

- Rename file
- Download zip
- Unzip file
- Delete Old and rename new to old

Unfortunately it crashes when it tries to rename the file with the error of "Can't rename file because it is being used by another process".

And this is the code in the updater

```
Public Function Rename(ToReplace As String, BeReplaced As String) As Boolean
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.RenameDirectory(ToReplace, BeReplaced)
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        Return False
    End Try
```

I've seen other examples where the Main application calls the updater but I just can't get it to work.

All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You should make your updater check whether a [process from your main app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) is still running and wait for it to exit.

Comment: Where is Updater.exe located?

Comment: Its a design issue. Before you start renaming or deleting any file you have to make sure the file is closed i.e. NOT readonly for Updater.exe. Add a delay(Thread.Sleep) in Updater.exe to allow main application close down properly.

Answer (score 0):

Run this when the updater is loaded.

```
Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("your app.exe")
For Each p As Process In processes
    p.Kill()
    p.WaitForExit()
```

Comment: Nope still crashes with the same error message. Which is really annoying because the updater works fine so long as it isn't called from the main program. Btw the updater is located in an entirely seperate folder to the main program.